# Hadoop: start-dfs/start-yarn.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, hadoop

It is giving me the two above errors despite me checking that both files exist in the directory and that hadoop has access to the folders.

I installed hadoop using the following tutorial: [link](http://amodernstory.com/2014/09/23/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-yosemite/)

Whats going wrong and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not have exported the path of this directory. Try giving `/entirepath/start-dfs.sh`.

Also in your .bash_rc file add HADOOP_HOME=/Pathtohadoopinstallationfolder.
Give the command `source .bash_rc` to source the bash_rc file.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error, but what I did wrong was copying the wrong path in ~/.profile file :
`alias hstart="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/sbin/start-dfs.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/sbin/start-yarn.sh"
alias hstop="/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/sbin/stop-yarn.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.6.0/sbin/stop-dfs.sh"`

In my case it was 3.0.0, so the path should be `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/start-dfs.sh;/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.0.0/sbin/start-yarn.sh`